Not able to connect my feature file to steps?
I am using pytest-bdd
I have created features file and written steps for it.
Code is also performing, But when I try to run code from feature file. It says Nothing Here.
Please Help ! Stuck in this from last 4 days.
I am using PyCharm tried searching for cucumber linked to feature file in my IDE and it was alright.
Tried upgrading all packages using for project.
Tried with Scenario Name , feature Name Tag. Feature file absolute Path. Still no LUCK!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
